# How to parse CSV data that contains newlines in field using pyspark

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

The source data looks like below. One of the field from 4th record has multiline string.

```
i1|j1|k1|l1|m1
i2|j2|k2|l2|m2
i3|j3|k3|l3|m3
i4|j4|k4|"l4 is
multiline data
multiline data"|m4
i5|j5|k5|l5|m5
```

I am reading this file through `sc.wholeTextFiles`

```
rdd= sc.wholeTextFiles("file.csv").flatMap(lambda x: x[1].split("\n"))
print rdd.take(100)
print rdd.count()
```

Output of `rdd.take(100)`:

```
[u'i1|j1|k1|l1|m1', u'i2|j2|k2|l2|m2', u'i3|j3|k3|l3|m3', u'i4|j4|k4|"l4 is', u'multiline data', u'multiline data"|m4', u'i5|j5|k5|l5|m5', u'']
```

Output of `rdd.count()`

```
8
```

The issue here is the `multiline` data is treated as a new record. Due to which the count is also increased. How can I treat that `multiline` data as one string value of the column(which is starting with `l4`) ?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to ignore newlines in double quotes with an advanced regex expression (only supported by the newer `regex` module):

```
"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\n
```

Which reads as

```
"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL) # match anything between double quotes and "forget" the match
|                     # or
\n                    # match a newline
```

---

In `Python` this would be:

```
import regex as re

data = """i1|j1|k1|l1|m1
i2|j2|k2|l2|m2
i3|j3|k3|l3|m3
i4|j4|k4|"l4 is
multiline data
multiline data"|m4
i5|j5|k5|l5|m5"""

rx = re.compile(r'"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\n')

lines = rx.split(data)
print(lines)
```

This would yield

```
['i1|j1|k1|l1|m1', 'i2|j2|k2|l2|m2', 'i3|j3|k3|l3|m3', 'i4|j4|k4|"l4 is\nmultiline data\nmultiline data"|m4', 'i5|j5|k5|l5|m5']
```

Be warned though that *escaped quotes* (`\"`) would break the mechanism.

Comment: thanks for your response, but I am looking to do this in pyspark.